# Dynamic regex returns false while static regex returns true

Tags: java, regex

For some reason `Matcher.find()` returns false when it should return true. Please check out the code below:

```
String[] strings = {
    "MSG://1/3/data1",
    "MSG://3/3/data3"
    "MSG://2/3/data2",
};

for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
        Pattern thePattern = Pattern.compile("^MSG://" + (j+1) + "/(.*)");
        //Pattern thePattern = Pattern.compile("^MSG://1/(.*)");
        Matcher theMatcher = thePattern.matcher(strings[j]);
        if (theMatcher.find()) {
            // Do something
        }
        else {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, the uncommented `thePattern = ...` line will cause `theMatcher.find()` to **always** return false. But if you comment that line, and uncomment the line right under it, it works as one would expect it to. I'm thinking there's something going on in the conversion from `int` to `String` but I'm not a Java guru. Any help anyone can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same result with both lines

Comment: Because the messages may be out of order and are being reconstructed.

Comment: Shouldn't first numbers in your string be `1`, `2`, `3` instead of `1`, `3`, `2`? Also you are not using `i` anywhere.

Comment: @Pshemo seems like you've found the problem

Comment: Actually, I assumed from the comma after `"MSG://2/3/data2",` that OP had inadvertently swapped the whole lines around, between the IDE and SO.  But it sucks when we have to guess what the code is actually supposed to be.

Comment: @lancemanfv Maybe. I have few ideas but will need more informations from OP regarding what this code should really do.

Comment: @Pshemo at least it passes 100% checks now and logically correct. What about OP, I can't understand a need of nested loops and a need of generation a new regexp instead of using `[0-9]`

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the bug is somewhere else entirely, and OP hasn't shown us all the code that they need to.  For example, maybe some problem inside the "true" branch of the "if" makes it look like it hasn't run, when in fact it has.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing but if your intention is to parse your data in order `MSG://1`, `MSG://2`, `MSG://3` then try changing `strings[j]` to `strings[i]`.

Or you can move creation of Pattern to outer loop and use it in inner one. This way you can still iterate over `strings[j]` and will not have to compile your pattern `n^n` times but just `n` times.

What I mean is

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    Pattern thePattern = Pattern.compile("^MSG://" + (i+1) + "/(.*)");
    for (int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < strings.length; j++) {
        Pattern thePattern = Pattern.compile("^MSG://" + (j+1) + "/(.*)");
```

Result:

```
MSG://1/3/data1
MSG://2/3/data2
MSG://3/3/data3
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I don't seem to have an issue when using Oracle JDK. But when I use OpenJDK, regardless of how I attempt to find the right message and extract the data, using `indexOf()` or `contains()`, I keep having failures. I even used a `StringBuilder` object to build a pattern and still get problems with matching.

So I'm going to chalk this up to a bug in OpenJDK and move on. Thanks for the advice on the `Pattern` object, @Pshemo. And thanks, everyone else, for your effort to help.

Comment: Actually, moving the `Pattern` object to the outer loop as suggested by @Pshemo fixed it. Not sure why, but oh well...